# Modeling Data - Invoices and Line Items

Tags: django, database-design, data-modeling

I'm creating a web based point of sale (think cash register) solution with Django as the backend. I've always taken the 'classic' approach of modeling invoices and their line items.

```
InvoiceTable
  id
  date
  customer
  salesperson
  discount
  shipping
  subtotal
  tax
  grand_total
  [...]

InvoiceLineItems
  invoice_id // foreign key
  product_id
  unit_price
  qty
  item_discount
  extended_price
  [...]
```

After attempting to research best practices, I've found that there aren't many - at least no definitive source that's widely used.

The Kimball Group suggests: "Rather than holding onto the operational notion of a transaction header “object,” we recommend that you bring all the dimensionality of the header down to the line items."

See http://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/10/02/design-tip-95-patterns-to-avoid-when-modeling-headerline-item-transactions/ and http://www.kimballgroup.com/2001/07/01/design-tip-25-designing-dimensional-models-for-parent-child-applications/.

I'm new to development (only having used desktop database software before) - but from my understanding this makes sense as we can drill down the data any way we want for reporting purposes (though I imagine we could do the same with the first method by joining the tables).

**My Questions**

- The invoice ID will need to be repeated for each row (so we can generate data like totals for the invoice). Is this an intentional feature of this way of modeling the data?
- We often have invoice level data like notes, discounts, shipping charges, etc. - How do we represent these using this method? Some discounts are product specific - so they belong on the line item anyway, others are invoice wide (think of a deal where you buy two separate products and receive a discount on the two) - we could we somehow allocate it across the line items? Same with shipping charges, allocate it by dividing it among the line items?
- What do we do with invoice 'notes' - we have printed and/or internal notes, would we put the data in the line items and just repeat it for each line item? That seems to go against data normalization. Put it in a related table?

  Any open source projects that use this method that I could take a look at? Not sure how to search for them.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. I count 6 questions in your rather long post. Please restrict your post to _one question_ that can be _answered_. See [the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). StackOverflow is a bit different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're confusing relational design and dimensional design.

A relational design is for facilitating transaction processing, and minimizing data anomalies and duplication. It's your operational database. A dimensional design is for facilitating analysis.

A relational design will have an invoices table and a line_items table and a dimensional design will have a company_invoices_customer fact table with a grain of invoice line item.

Since this is for POS, I assume you want a relational design first.

As for your questions:

First there are tons of good data modelling patterns for this scenario. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831

> The invoice ID will need to be repeated for each row (so we can
>   generate data like totals for the invoice). Is this an intentional
>   feature of this way of modeling the data?

Yes

> We often have invoice level data like notes, discounts, shipping
>   charges, etc. - How do we represent these using this method?

Probably easiest/simplest to have a "notes" field on the invoice table.

For charges and discounts you should use abstraction (see Table Inheritance), and add them as Order Adjustments. See the book by Silverston in the link above.

> Some discounts are product specific - so they belong on the line item
>   anyway, others are invoice wide (think of a deal where you buy two
>   separate products and receive a discount on the two) - we could we
>   somehow allocate it across the line items?

The price of the item should be calculated at runtime based on it's default price, and any discounts or charges that apply in the current "scenario", example discount for government, nearby, on sale day. You could have hierarchical line items that reference each other, to keep things in order. Again, see Silverston book.

> What do we do with invoice 'notes' - we have printed and/or internal
>   notes, would we put the data in the line items and just repeat it for
>   each line item?

If you want line item notes, add a notes column on the line items table.

> That seems to go against data normalization. Put it in a related
>   table?

If notes are nullable, and you want to be strict about normalization, then yes, add a invoice_notes table.

Comment: That's essentially it, reading books on dimension design led me to believe that I should somehow be using a dimensional approach even though a relational one with a invoice header and invoice line items child makes much more sense. Am I correct in assuming that the dimensional design is used more for data analysis?

Comment: Yes, if you want to make it easy for analysts to analyze your invoice data then that's where a data warehouse / dimensional design would come in. But if you are working on a interactive standard web app then you probably want a relational design.